# How to add keybindings in Visual Studio Code for the R terminal

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I've succesfully added keybindings for `%>%` and `<-` when working with R scripts or Rmarkdown in Visual Studio Code by adding the following to my `keybindings.json` file:

```
    {
      "key": "Ctrl+Shift+m",
      "command": "type",
      "args": { "text": " %>% " },
      "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == r"
    },
    {
      "key": "Alt+-",
      "command": "type",
      "args": { "text": " <- " },
      "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == r"
    },
    {
      "key": "Ctrl+Shift+m",
      "command": "type",
      "args": { "text": " %>% " },
      "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == rmd"
    },
    {
      "key": "Alt+-",
      "command": "type",
      "args": { "text": " <- " },
      "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == rmd"
    },
```

But I can't figure how to do that for my R terminal inside Visual Studio Code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to change the `when` part to have `terminalFocus`. For instance, if you want to set up `Ctrl + l` to clear terminal while the focus is in terminal:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+l",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.clear",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still doesn't work.
This is how the my command looks like in my settings.json:
```
 {
   "key": "Alt+u",
   "command": "type",
   "args": { "text": " <- " },
   "when": "terminalFocus"
 },
```
any ideas?

Comment: the text command is only for the editor I believe. Try the command `workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence` with the same args.

Comment: DAMNNNNNNNNN that workss. Thank you!
This is how it looks like:
 {
   "key": "Alt+-",
   "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
   "args": { "text": " <- " },
   "when": "terminalFocus"
 },

Answer (score 3):

@AdroMine found the way to do it.
I'll just post the updated keybindings.json so that others can use it:

```
[
    // OTHER KEYBINDINGS,


 
    // keybindings for R scripts. 
    {
      "key": "Ctrl+Shift+m",
      "command": "type",
      "args": { "text": " %>% " },
      "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == r"
    },
    {
      "key": "Alt+-",
      "command": "type",
      "args": { "text": " <- " },
      "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == r"
    },
    // keybindings for Rmarkdown
    {
      "key": "Ctrl+Shift+m",
      "command": "type",
      "args": { "text": " %>% " },
      "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == rmd"
    },
    {
      "key": "Alt+-",
      "command": "type",
      "args": { "text": " <- " },
      "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == rmd"
    },
    // keybindings for R terminal (radian included)
    {
      "key": "Ctrl+Shift+m",
      "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
      "args": { "text": " %>% " },
      "when": "terminalFocus"
    },
    {
      "key": "Alt+-",
      "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
      "args": { "text": " <- " },
      "when": "terminalFocus"
    },
    // OTHER KEYBINDINGS

]
```

Comment: you can further reduce these by using regex for editorLangId: `editorLangId =~ /r|rmd/`, =~ is match operator (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_conditional-operators)